# Icon setting in Gridview in Android

Tags: android

I have created a launcher screen following Android samples given in sdk. Now I want my icons to completely fill up the screen. Now if I drag one image view partially it remains as it is in the screen. I want my screen to adjust automatically upon dragging.

I can't post my screenshot here as it isn't allowed.
Hope my question is clear. Now please help me regarding this issue.Thanks in Advance.

Thanks,
Android developer

Answer (score 0):

You must googling whatever you need to do. If you didn't get anything else means.  After, that ask here. There are lot of source code available for Drag and Drap imageView in Gridview.

```
public void onDragEnter(DragSource source, int x, int y, int xOffset, int yOffset,
    DragView dragView, Object dragInfo) {
int bg = mEmpty ? R.color.cell_empty_hover : R.color.cell_filled_hover;
setBackgroundResource (bg);
}

public void onDragExit(DragSource source, int x, int y, int xOffset, int yOffset,
    DragView dragView, Object dragInfo) {
int bg = mEmpty ? R.color.cell_empty : R.color.cell_filled;
setBackgroundResource (bg);
}
```

These are all the important methods for Drag&Drop the Images.

Take the [Source Code.](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/drag-drop-for-android-gridview/)

Comment: SPK, I don't want to implement drag & drop feature. What I want is, my gridview should contain only complete icons,not partial ones. if nay one slides little bit downward one may get to see textview of some icons coming up. I want if any incomplete icon is showing, then my screen should adjust to it automatically like samsung galaxy. I can't post image here.

Comment: Folks, got the answer. I have to implement onscrollchangelistener. From there, we can get the position where the scroll ends. Now On it, I can set my icons.